# How to convert from local to UTC within Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a client app that sends dates in local time to a Rest Api. An example date is:

```
"2016-09-12T10:05:44.583694+02:00"
```

The Rest Api then needs to forward these dates in Utc to a SOAP service, for example:

```
"2016-09-12T08:05:44Z"
```

I'm using the following converter to convert date values from local time to Utc:

```
public class UtcDateTimeConverter : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DateTime);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        writer.WriteValue(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)value, DateTimeKind.Utc)));
    }
}
```

The above converter is placed as an attribute on all `DateTime` properties of the POCO classes. These classes are used both by the client app and Rest Api.

However, the converter is not converting from local to Utc.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't convert *within* Json - it's just the container format and does not actively *do* something. You need to convert either on server or frontend side.

Comment: I haven't used it, but my reading of the docs is that `DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)value, DateTimeKind.Utc))` means you are declaring that `value` is in UTC time (even if it isn't). Therefore when to you run `ToUniversalTime` on that value, it thinks it's already in UTC and doesn't convert it. That's my guess. If I'm correct you need to specify the timezone that `value` actually _is_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the conversion should only take place in the server, the serialization from client to server was done as follow by using one of the overload methods which requires one or more converters:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Formatting.Indented, new UtcDateTimeConverter())
```

When deserializing from soap service to server, the same applies:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(message, new UtcDateTimeConverter())
```

The following change was done in the custom converter:

```
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var date = (DateTime)value;
        if (date.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(date));
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteValue(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(date));
        }
    }
```

Furthermore, all the attribute was removed from all `DateTime` properties.